# Express + Sequelize + bcrypt => question about scaffolding vis a vis inability to validate password

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to learn how to control sequelize on Node.js and i've created a terse register/login, atm I can't access my `user.validPassword()` method.

Application works great to include all process', the only issue is with password validation.

### /index.js

```
const initConnection = async function () {
    httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`listening at https://localhost:${port}`)
    });

    //db ops
    const db = require("./models");
    await db.sequelize.sync();

}
```

### /models/index.js

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: dbConfig.pool.max,
        min: dbConfig.pool.min,
        acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
        idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
    }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.User = require("./User.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
console.log({user: db.User});

module.exports = db;
```

### /models/User.model.js

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define("user", {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,

        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,
        },

    },{
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10, 'a');
                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            },
            beforeUpdate:async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10, 'a');
                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            }
        },
        instanceMethods: {
            validPassword: (password) => {
                return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
            }
        }
    });
```

### /controllers/User.controller.js

```
const db = require("../models");
const path = require("path");
const User = db.User;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op; //sql operators

exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    };

    const isValidated = User.validPassword(user.password);
    console.log({isValidated});
};
```

Error: `TypeError: User.validPassword is not a function`

I'm trying to wrap my head around this for last couple of hours with no avail.

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: Two things.  1. Sequelize V4 removed `instanceMethods`. You need to use `const User = sequelize.define(...); User.prototype.validPassword = (password) => {...}`.   2. You are defining an instance method but you are calling a class method.  `User.classMethod()` vs `user.instanceMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

sequelize version >4 is changed the way instance methods are defined.

[you can also refer to this link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8030)

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("user", {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,

        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: 0,
        },

    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10, 'a');
                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            },
            beforeUpdate: async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10, 'a');
                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    User.validPassword = (password) => {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    }
    return User;
}
```